# Is there a way to build an IOS Unity build on windows

Tags: ios, windows, unity-game-engine, firebase

Is there a way to build an IOS Unity build on windows with firebase?
Im getting this error:

```
Firebase iOS builds are not supported on Windows. Please build on a OSX machine instead.
UnityEngine.Debug:LogError(Object)
Firebase.Editor.XcodeProjectPatcher:CheckBuildEnvironment()
Firebase.Editor.XcodeProjectPatcher:.cctor()
UnityEditor.EditorAssemblies:ProcessInitializeOnLoadAttributes()
```

Answer (score 4):

You technically can, but will require more work.

The plugin that comes with firebase depends on cocoapods to handle transient dependencies. If you look at the Assets -> PlayServicesResolver -> IOSResolver -> Settings

You can configure it to generate the podfile but not do the remaining steps.

The other steps would fail because cocoapods does not work on windows.

Finally after you copy the build directory to your mac to build and deploy, you'll just have to run the cocoapods step manually:

`pod install`

It should work after that if you use the xcodeworkspace that's generated from the pod tool to build and run.

Comment: Furthermore, when opening the project make sure to use .workspace file and not .xcodeproj. Otherwise, you will get a build error e.g. Library not found for -IFirebaseAuth

Answer (score -1):

Firebase in unity projects for ios requires Xcode, it is in the requirements listed on their page, also unity specifies the same, you cannot compile for iOS outside their platform.

Here is the official documentation:
https://unity3d.com/unity/system-requirements 
https://firebase.google.com/docs/unity/setup

Comment: Before adding firebase I was able to build for IOS on my windows computer and then copy it to a mac and build it in Xcode. Now I cant do that because of firebase.